# DISTINCT COUNT per day sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to be able to COUNT DISTINCT IPs per day and then COUNT them all together.

Basically Monday I get 3 distinct IPs and out of those 3, two of them visited the page twice so I have a total of 5 records. On Tuesday I get 1 IP that was from Monday and 2 new distinct IPs. I want to be able to count 3 distinct IPs for Monday and 3 distinct IPs for tuesday and add them all together totaling 6 records. Here is my code:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT track.ip) AS tracks
FROM user, track
WHERE track.user_id = $user_id
GROUP BY $user_id
ORDER BY tracks
LIMIT 1
```

How can I COUNT my DISTINCT ips?

Comment: Why would `$user_id` be a variable in the `GROUP BY`?? Is it a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select sum(NumIpsPerDay)
from (select date(TheDayCol) as d, count(distinct t.ip) as NumIpsPerDay
      from track t
      group by date(TheDayCol) 
     ) t;
```

This calculates the number of distinct IPs on each day and then calculates the sum.

Comment: This will only work is TheDayCol is the same for all rows with the same day. If you have a datetime for the date then you will need to pull out or truncate the date in a way that can be grouped.

Comment: @dagarrison . . . In MySQL, the `date()` function truncates a date time to the date.